# What are the compression types supported in parquet

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, compression, parquet

I was writing data on Hadoop and hive in parquet format using spark. I want to enable compression but i can only find 2 types on compression - snappy and Gzip being used most of the times. Does parquet support any other compression like Deflate and lzo also?

Answer (score 22):

The supported compression types for Apache Parquet are specified in the `parquet-format` repository:

```
/**
 * Supported compression algorithms.
 *
 * Codecs added in 2.4 can be read by readers based on 2.4 and later.
 * Codec support may vary between readers based on the format version and
 * libraries available at runtime. Gzip, Snappy, and LZ4 codecs are
 * widely available, while Zstd and Brotli require additional libraries.
 */
enum CompressionCodec {
  UNCOMPRESSED = 0;
  SNAPPY = 1;
  GZIP = 2;
  LZO = 3;
  BROTLI = 4; // Added in 2.4
  LZ4 = 5;    // Added in 2.4
  ZSTD = 6;   // Added in 2.4
}
```

> https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/54e6133e887a6ea90501ddd72fff5312b7038a7c/src/main/thrift/parquet.thrift#L461

Snappy and Gzip are the most commonly used ones and are supported by all implementations. LZ4 and ZSTD yield better results the former two but are a rather new addition to the format, so they are only supported in the newer versions of some of the implementations.

Answer (score 11):

### In Spark 2.1

From the [Spark source code, branch 2.1](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala):

> You can set the following Parquet-specific option(s) for writing
> Parquet files:
> **`compression`** (default is the value specified in `spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec`): compression codec to use when
> saving to file. This can be one of the known case-insensitive shorten
> names (`none`, `snappy`, `gzip`, and `lzo`).
> This will
> override`spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec`
> ...

### In Spark 2.4 / 3.0

overall supported compresssions are: `none`, `uncompressed`, `snappy`, `gzip`, `lzo`, `brotli`, `lz4`, and `zstd`